# Replace \r\r\n with \n in byte array java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a ByteArrayOutputStream which I converted toByteArray and after that I need to replace all \r\r\n with \n

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Break it down into baby steps, it always helps me. First figure out "how to replace a character in a byte array in java" then try to do it for \r\r\n to \n like you want.

Comment: It might be easier to wrap your ByteArrayOutputStream in another stream that strips the `\r` characters before writing them, since removing bytes from an array is a tedious and expensive operation.

Comment: Please give some context. Can you replace a single character with a different one? Can you write loops? How does the code you have look like? So that we hae a foundation for making proposals.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about 0x0D 0x0A characters  you can use intermediate `String` and `replaceAll` method to do that:

```
byte[] result = new String(myByteArray).replaceAll("\r\r\n", "\n").getBytes();
```